# Java: Error in one program, but none in another. "Illegal start or type"

Tags: java

The title is long.. I know... but anyways...

For some odd reason, I am getting the error "Illegal start of type" in one program, but when I compare it to a program I made before. The error does not show up there. And for some odd reason, in the code I am making now. I am also getting a " expected" error as well.

The Code I am making now goes as this

```
public class Hero {
    public static Dice d = new Dice();
    public String n;
    public int s, p ,i;
    public int currentHP;
    public int maxHP = 100;
    public int maxMP = 100;
    public int maxSP = 100;

    public Hero(String n, int s, int p, int i,){ //illegal start of type
        this.n = n;
        this.s = s;
        this.p = p;
        this.i = i;
        this.currentHP = maxHP;
    }
    public int Attack(){
        int damage;
        damage = (p*s) + d.Stats();
    }
//<identifier> expected

}
```

Compared to a program I made before

```
public class Character implements Arma {
public static Dice d = new Dice();
public String n;
public int s, p, i;
public int currentHP;
public int MP;
public int maxHP = d.Health();
public int maxMP = d.Health();

public Character (String n, int s, int p, int i){
    this.n = n;
    this.s = s;
    this.p = p;
    this.i = i;
    this.currentHP = maxHP;
    this.MP = maxMP;
}
        public int attack()
{
    int damage;
    damage = ((s * p) + i) + d.Dice();
    return damage;
}
```

I am not getting any errors here in Character... It is baffling me to no end... is it just because I have not finished the entire code for Hero yet? but that doesn't make sense because the Character code was just fine when I made it, so why is the Hero code acting up?

P.S. I made the Character code when I was studying. It; however, is still entirely made from my mind. The Hero code is essentially just a copy reformatted.

P.P.S. The Arma code is just an interface that was to "upgrade" the Character class so it could go toe to toe with another code we had to make in class. It literally does nothing other than give the Character code weapons.

Comment: Which IDE you are using? which did not show you the extra comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo here `public Hero(String n, int s, int p, int i,)`

See you have `,` after `int i` remove that and change to this one:

`public Hero(String n, int s, int p, int i)`

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the last comma

```
public Hero(String n, int s, int p, int i,){ //illegal start of type
```

so it becomes

```
public Hero(String n, int s, int p, int i) {
```